# Remote event receiver on sharepoint 2013 online does not work

Tags: event-receivers, event-handlers, office-365

I recently started to develop Sharepoint 2013 on my office 365 account.

The problem is that remote event receivers which I attach to deploying application do not work.

I mean that they should listen to particular events and then perform action. And it seems that they even do not listen to anything – they don't fire anytime.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio by default creates an elements.xml file to deploy Remote Event Receiver. Which mean it is actually deployed to App web (web cretaed specifically for your SharePoint application), not the Host web (where your actual content is).

Answer (score 0):

Please read the following two full step-by-step articles (with information about service bus configuration) about Remote Event Recevers in SharePoint Online:

1) Creating and Debugging of Remote Event Receivers for SharePoint Online 
http://blog.virtosoftware.com/2014/12/creating-and-debugging-of-remote-event.html

2) Adding Remote Event Receivers to list on Host web + Debugging
http://blog.virtosoftware.com/2015/01/adding-remote-event-receivers-to-list.html